# What is the simplest code with a for loop that you would use to represent a Log(n) BigO notation?

Tags: javascript, performance, testing, big-o

I would like to know a clear and simple code that can be used to teach a O(log(n)) case.

Its quite simple to see examples for O(n) and O(n²) as a `for loop` and a `nested for loop` respectively. But I can't think of a trivial and simple example for O(log(n)).

O(n):

```
function N(n) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
      console.log(i);
    }
}
```

O(n²):

```
function N2(n) {
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++){
      console.log(i,j);
    }
  }
}
```

**What would be the simplest and direct form of a code that would result in a O(log(n))?**

Comment: Okay, here's a straight-forward one: `for (i = 0; i < Math.log(n); i++)`?

Comment: A binary search in recursive form: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/

Comment: You could also do `for (i=0; i<n; i = i *2)`

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < Math.log(n); i++)` do work but it dosen't evolve the conversation... since we are forcing a log in your condition. From the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17122807/big-o-ologn-code-example) - seems that `while` is the key... and the binary search is definitely not the most trivial example.

Comment: Binary search is quite simple and very classic example of this behaviour. Yes, it's slightly more complex than a linear search is but that doesn't make it *hard*.

Comment: @RodrigoCosta There's no such thing as _they took away 25rep points_, if there is a duplicate, there is a duplicate,... and what Kyle suggested is in the duplicate, though it uses `while` instead, but same logic.

Comment: @RodrigoCosta That isn't how rep works.  Kyle wrote a comment, not an answer, and comments do not earn rep.  If it's a duplicate, then its a duplicate, and should be closed as such.

Comment: @RodrigoCosta That would not have denied him that rep.  Closing as a duplicate doesn't take rep away from users.  Besides, *he didn't write an answer*.

Comment: @RodrigoCosta And I say, if there is a duplicate, no one should answer and instead vote/flag to close as a dupe, meaning, one shouldn't get points for existing answers already solve a question.